# Javascript finding elements by position

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I'm looking for the best way to find all elements that fall within a range of pixels from the top of the page.

I've got this very simple `inRange` test now

```
function inRange(el, from, to) {
  var top = el.offset().top;

  // if el is above from
  if(top < from) {
    return false;
  }

  // if el is below to
  if(top > to) {
    return false;
  }

  // el is in range
  return true;
}
```

which I'm using with something like

```
$(".search").each(function() {
  var el = $(this);
  el.toggleClass('found', inRange(el, 40, 50));
});
```

, which does work. But if there are a large number of elements that match the query, `.search` in this case, it massively inefficient.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Do you mean a specific number of pixels from the top of their container?  jQuery's `.offset()` returns position in the document, not in your container.  `.position()` is relevant to the parent.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, that was unclear. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to use native `for` loops instead of `$.each`.  If you measure the results, you can see it's actually fairly significant ([95% faster](http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-each-vs-for-loop)).  Do this:

```
var $search = $(".search");
for (var i = 0; i < $search.length; i++) {
    if (inRange($search[i], 40, 50)) {
      $($search[i]).toggleClass('found', true);
    }
}
```

You initialize far less jQuery objects and utilize the native `for` loop, optimized for you by the browser.

Comment: Explain how this initializes any fewer jQuery objects?  I see both your code and the OP's code doing `$(".search").length + 1` jQuery objects.  I'd suggest you test your actual code vs. the OP's code rather than use some other benchmark to claim 95% faster.  I'm not discounting that the `for` loop may be faster (particularly in Chrome), but the way you've concluded it isn't from measuring your actual code.

Comment: Worst case scenario it's the same, but since only DOM elements that evaluate to true from `inRange` call `toggleClass`, this should reduce overhead on average.

Comment: But, how do you know the OP doesn't need to remove the `"found"` class when it's not `inRange()`.  Your code doesn't do the same thing as the OP's.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `inRange()` can be simplified to this:

```
function inRange(el, from, to) {
  var top = el.offset().top;
  return top >= from && top <= to;
}
```

You'd have to measure in jsPerf or some tool like that to see how much of a performance difference that makes.